# Check the parent checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I am trying to write a js func that if I check a child checkbox the parent checkbox also checks, if not already checked. I am using jquery here is my html:

```
      <ul id="ulParent" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;">
            <li style="margin: 0 0 5px 0;">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liParent" id="p1" />Parent1
                <ul id="ulParent" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liChild" id="c1" onclick="checkParent(this);" />Child1
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liChild" id="c2" onclick="checkParent(this);"/>Child2
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liChild" id="c3" onclick="checkParent(this);"/>Child3
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liChild" id="c4" onclick="checkParent(this);"/>Child4
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li style="margin: 0 0 5px 0;">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liParent" id="p2" />Parent2
                <ul id="ulParent" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liChild" id="c1" onclick="checkParent(this);" />Child1
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liChild" id="c2" onclick="checkParent(this);"/>Child2
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liChild" id="c3" onclick="checkParent(this);"/>Child3
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="liChild" id="c4" onclick="checkParent(this);"/>Child4
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

JS Func

```
function checkParent(child){

if (child != null) {

    // if child is checked we need to check the parent category       
    if (child.checked) {
    // get the parent checkbox and check it if not check....need help here....
           $(child).parent().parent().parent()......

       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you setting a css color when trying to check the parent checkbox? Is this just for testing to see if the selector worked?

Comment: You will also want to update your input controls. You should have the attribute type="checkbox" in them. Most browsers will not work right without this. FF3 for example shows your current markup as all textboxes, not checkboxes.

Comment: oops, sorry i just madea simple example rather than copy and pasting all my code.... i have the type in my actual code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd remove the inline javascript in your HTML and use jQuery binding to bind the check event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.liChild').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

This will bind the event you're looking for to any input with the class liChild automatically without all those onclicks.

Comment: I think you want closest and not parent. Parent will only look up step up, while closest will keep going until it finds the selector.

Comment: *Closest* or *Parents* will work, because *Parents* gets ancestors, but *Parent* just gets the parent, which is not high enough in this case.  Arranging it like this is a good idea though.

Comment: If you upgrade to the new jQuery 1.4, you could use $(this).parentsUntil('.liParent').attr('checked', true) (assuming based on sample markup the parent checkbox has the class liParent...

Answer (score 0):

This will work, based on your structure:

`$(child).parent().parent().prev().attr('checked', true);`

or

`$(child).closest('ul').prev().attr('checked', true);;`