# How not to uncheck parent's checkbox if one of the target checkbox's siblings is checked

Tags: jquery, onchange, siblings, parents

How can I not to uncheck parent's checkbox if one of the target checkbox's siblings is checked?

Below is the code I modified from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119220/check-the-parent-checkbox-with-jquery).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.liChild').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parents('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        }
        else
        {
            if($(this).parents('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').not(':checked')) 
                $(this).parents('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

The idea is to check all parents' checkboxes no matter how deep the target checkbox is. Then uncheck all parents' checkboxes again if the target checkbox is unchecked.

My trouble is I dont want to uncheck parents' checkboxes if the target checkbox's **sibling** is checked.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6wky/).

**EDIT:**

I worked out my own solution, thanks guys for the help.

```
 $('input.liChild').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parents('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
            //alert($(this).parents().siblings().find('input:checkbox:checked').length);
            //$(this).parents().siblings().css({background:'red'});
            //$(this).parent().children().css({background:'red'});
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().children().find('input:checkbox:checked').attr('checked', false);

            if($(this).parents().siblings().find('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) 
                $(this).parents('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);


        }
    });
```

Comment: Please don't post your solution inside the question. Post it as new answer instead. You can mark it accepted if you end up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little something like this:

```
$('input.liChild').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul')
           .siblings('input:checkbox')
           .prop('checked', $(this).closest('ul')
                                   .children()
                                   .children('input:checkbox')
                                   .is(':checked'))
           .first().change();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D6wky/4/

The changed checkbox's parent is found with:

```
$(this).closest('ul').siblings('input:checkbox')
```

...and then the parent's `checked` property is set to the result of:

```
$(this).closest('ul').children().children('input:checkbox').is(':checked')
```

...where `.is(':checked')` will return `true` if *any* of the elements in the jQuery object it is called on are checked.

Then `.change()` is called on the parent so that the effect cascades upwards. (EDIT: I think you can omit the `.first()` from the above - at the time I thought I needed it, and it doesn't hurt so I'll leave it since I can't be bothered changing the demo to match.)

Comment: I think children checkboxes must become checked/unchecked if you check/uncheck their parent checkbox.

Comment: @Riateche - I wondered about that, but the question doesn't say so so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/D6wky/5/

```
$('input.liChild').on("change", function() {
  //set the same value for all chilren
  $(this).parent().find('input.liChild').attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));

  //we need to run the next block several times
  //until nothing is changed on an iteration
  var something_changed = true;
  while(something_changed) {
    something_changed = false;
    $('input.liChild').each(function() {
      var childs = $(this).parent().find('input.liChild').not(this);
      if (childs.length > 0) {
        //this input has children, so its value must be adjusted 
        //to match children's values
        var anything_checked = childs.filter(":checked").length > 0;
        if ($(this).is(":checked") != anything_checked) {
          $(this).attr("checked", anything_checked);
          //value changed, we need to re-run this procedure 
          //to adjust value of parent checkbox of this item
          something_changed = true;
        }
      }
    });
  };
});
```

I've added `liChild` class to the first checkbox. Also, your second-level list is broken with `</ul><ul>`. I've removed these tags to make things work properly.